# ImportError when using console_scripts in setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to build a program called `dnsrep` in Python, I am using setuptools so that I can call the `dnsrep` module without using the command `python dnsrep`. The `setup.py` script I wrote is given below:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='dnsrep',
    version='0.1',
    description='Program that gives a reputation score to url\'s\n.',
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['dnsrep = dnsrep:main']
    },
    zip_safe=True,
)
```

I install the module by using the command:

```
python setup.py install
```

My module gets registered but when I run it I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/dnsrep", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('dnsrep==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'dnsrep')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 521, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2632, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2312, in load
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2318, in resolve
ImportError: No module named dnsrep
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to install your python script, before you can call it via your defined `entry point`

This is my dummy project:

```
dnsrep/
├── dnsrep.py
└── setup.py
```

This is how `setup.py` looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='dnsrep',
    version='0.1',
    description='Program that gives a reputation score to url\'s\n.',
    py_modules=['dnsrep'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['dnsrep = dnsrep:main']
    },
    zip_safe=True,
)
```

Note the argument `py_modules=['dnsrep']`, which installs `dnsrep.py` as a new module.

Finally, this is my dummy implementation of `dnsrep.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def main():
    print("Hey, it works!")
```

After installing, everything works as expected and `$ dnsrep` prints: `Hey, it works!`

Comment: For more info, see https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#py-modules