# Using setup.py install, how can I generate a working standalone command line script?

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm trying to make my Python command-line app as self-installing as possible for some Mac users in my company by registering it as a "command-line accessible tool" using `setup.py` as described [here](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point).

My project tree (simplified) looks like so:

```
my-app
 |-app.py
 |-setup.py
```

Building off [Kenneth Reitz's example](https://github.com/kennethreitz/setup.py), here's my setup.py script:

```
setup(
    name=my-app,
    ...
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests',)),

    # For entry point. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/28471597/9381758.
    py_modules=['app'],

    # Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11717581/9381758.
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['my-app = app:main']
    }
)
```

When I run `python setup.py install`, it installs to my pyenv directory:

```
~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/bin/my-app
```

This works:

```
$ ~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/bin/my-app -h 
usage: my-app [-h]
```

This doesn't:

```
$ my-app -h 
-bash: my-app: command not found
```

Is there an elegant way to update my `setup.py` script so that after install end-users will be able to run the `my-app` command without further tweaks or including the full path?

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem.

```
setup(
    other args ...
    scripts = ['my-app/script.py']
)
```

In your case try

```
setup(
    other args ...
    scripts = ['app.py']
)
```

Comment: I considered this, but then wouldn't I have to call `app -h`? I like the idea of aliasing the command. Using the first example I could achieve that effect by writing a wrapper script under `bin/my-app` but that feels fussy and redundant. Alternately, if I followed Python convention and renamed `app.py` to `my_app.py`, I guess that would also sorta work.